# Angular style css not overwritten by default style using 'ngx-pagination'

Tags: html, css, angular, web-component, ngx-pagination

I'm currently using the **'ngx-pagination'** module from Michael Bromley. The module is working fine, but it seems to be the only pagination module that doesn't use the existing theme css. Now it looks like:

[image]

Reading his [explanation](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#styling), it seems that it should be easy by simply override the css by adding **`/deep/`**. Well, it doesn't work... Some people say it's **'deprecated'**, so I've tried adding **`!important`**, but that doesn't seem to work as well.

See -> **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3swdg**

In the **'app.component.css'** I've uploaded the theme css and in the end it should look like (see [documentation](http://www.urbanui.com/calmui/template/demo/vertical-light-sidebar/pages/ui-features/pagination.html)):

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick working [stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbsnoh?file=src/app/app.component.css).

```
.pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination .current {
    background: red;
  }

  .pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination li {
    border: 1px solid #CCCC;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }

   .pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination a::after{
     display: none;
   }

   .pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination li::before{
     display: none;
   }

    .pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination li::after{
     display: none;
   }

    .pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination a::before{
     display: none;
   }
```

using `/deep` . You can polish the css better but you'll get the idea from this.

Comment: Thanks for your example. There it indeed works, but what I actually want is to use my theme css. So, I've applied /deep/ as you've done, but it still doesn't work. See -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9qw9g

Comment: @Jamie: I tried adding `.pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination .current` in the last styling block and it worked. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akpiuq?file=src/app/app.component.css) is the demo code. You need to pick the exact class.

Comment: @Shashank_Vivek: thank you. I'll try it tonight to make it completely the same as my  current theme css. Appreciated your help :)